Asymptotic for $\sum_{n \leq x} \phi^*(n)$
I'd like to find an asymptotic for $\sum_{n \leq x} \phi^*(n)$ where $\phi^*(n)$ is the number of primitive Dirichlet characters mod n. It's not too hard to show that $\phi^*=\phi \star\mu$, but using this I can't see how to get a bound better than $O(x^2)$, which is no better than the one for $\sum_{n \leq x} \phi(n)=\frac{x^2}{2\zeta(2)}+O(x\log x)$, even though $\phi^*$ should be much smaller. Is there a way we can do better?

The asymptotic formula will be
$$
\sum_{n\le x} \phi^*(n) \sim \frac{x^2}{2\zeta(2)^2}.
$$
For a proof, one could either use Perron's formula together with the Dirichlet series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi^*(n)n^{-s} = \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)^2},
$$
or else use the Dirichlet hyperbola method with $\phi^* = id\star(\mu\star\mu)$ where $id$ is the identity function.
